# Continuity and compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $g:X\to Y$ a continuous function. Define $G :\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)\to\mathcal{C}(X,Z)$ by $G(f)=f\circ g$. Show that $G$ is continuous with respect to the compact-open topology. Note that we shall not use locally compact Hausdorff property here.

My idea is suppose $f\circ g\in S(C_2,U_2)$ where the subbasis element is defined as
\begin{equation*}
    S(C_2,U_2)=\{h:h\in\mathcal{C}(X,Z), h(C_2)\subseteq U_2\}
\end{equation*}
where $C_2$ is a compact subset of $X$ and $U_2$ is an open set on $Z$. Now we need to find $S(C_1,U_1)$ such that $f\circ g\in G(S(C_1,U_1))\subseteq S(C_2,U_2)$, where $S(C_1,U_1)$ is defined as
\begin{equation*}
    S(C_1,U_1)=\{h:h\in\mathcal{C}(Y,Z), h(C_1)\subseteq U_1\}
\end{equation*}
$C_1$ is a compact subset of $Y$ and $U_1$ is an open set on $Z$. However, since I am very new to this part, I have no idea how to do that. Any help please?

Comment: Have you considered trying to show that the sets $G^{-1}(S(C,U))$ are open? (Hint: you can express these as subbasic opens in $C(Y,Z)$ using the continuity of $g$).

Comment: @Tyrone I once tried your method but soon I found that didn't work. What exactly is your idea?

Comment: If $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, then $g(K)$ is a compact subset of $Y$ (as $g$ is continuous). Given $f:Y\rightarrow Z$, the map $G(f)=f\circ g$ takes $K$ into an open $U\subseteq Z$ if and only if $f$ takes $g(K)$ into $U$. Can you see how to identify $S(g(K),U)$ and $G^{-1}(S(K,U))$?

Comment: @Tyrone My idea is suppose $f\circ g\in S(C_2,U_2)$ and find $S(C_1,U_1)$ such that $f\circ g\in G(S(C_1,U_1))\subseteq S(C_2,U_2)$. I think my method works if I set $C_1=g(C_2)$ and $U_1=U_2$ so we have $f\circ g\in G(S(g(C_2),U_2))\subseteq S(C_2,U_2)$.

Comment: Your method works. What I am saying is that it works because $G^{-1}(S(C,U))=S(g(C),U)$.